# A simple event listener in useEffect causing several warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Getting started with React Hooks. I'm trying to add a event listener on the window that calls a function upon clicking 'Enter'. This function will perform a few API requests and use state variables to pass the appropiate query string and update the data state afterwards.

However I have a problem - this is the error I get:

**React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps**

This is the code:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
 const [location, setLocation] = useState('');

 useEffect(() => {

    function handleKeyPress(e) {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
        getData();
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    };
 }, [])

 function getData() {
    setData([]);

    fetch(`${URL}/api-1?search=${search}&location=${location}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setData(cur => [...cur, ...data]));

    fetch(`${URL}/api-2?search=${search}&location=${location}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setData(cur => [...cur, ...data]));
  }
```

Like the error message says, it's missing getData as a dependency in the dependency array, I've tried to add it but get another error message:

**The 'getData' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 66) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the 'getData' definition into its own useCallback() Hook**

Then I tried to define a useCallback hook and refactored the useEffect and function call as follows:

```
function getData(searchArg, locationArg) {
    setData([]);

    fetch(`${URL}/api-1?search=${searchArg}&location=${locationArg}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setData(cur => [...cur, ...data]));

    fetch(`${URL}/api-2?search=${searchArg}&location=${locationArg}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setData(cur => [...cur, ...data]));
  }

const getDataMemo = useCallback(() => {
  getData(search, location);
}, [search, location]);

useEffect(() => {

  function handleKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
       getDataMemo();
    }
   }

   window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);

   return () => {
     window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
   };
}, [getDataMemo])
```

Now I get no warnings but seems like a lot of hassle just to add a 'Enter' event listener to fire off 1 function. In addition I had to add arguments to my function instead of just using search and location variables directly.

Is this the right approach or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right approach and it does seem like a lot of hassle, but there is a lot going on. To make it easier and more re-usable you can abstract a lot of the code into its own hook.

This is the hook I use

```
const useKeyDown = (key, handler) => {
  // Create a ref that stores handler
  const savedHandler = useRef();
  // Make sure we always have the latest handler.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedHandler.current = handler;
  }, [handler]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = event => {
      if (event.key === key) {
        savedHandler.current();
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, [key]);
};
```

The code in you component would then look like:

```
const getData = () => {
  console.log("Use these vars directly", search, location);
};
const getDataMemo = useCallback(getData, [search, location]);
useKeyDown("Enter", getDataMemo);
```